# Why won't the function work?

Tags: javascript

So, I am going through "JavaScript Allonge" and there is this function, to simulate array's `.length` function:

```
const length = ([first, ...rest]) =>
  first === undefined
    ? 0
    : 1 + length(rest);
```

Now, if I re-write the function as:

```
var lengthy = (first, ...rest) => 
    first === undefined ? 0 : 1 + lengthy(rest)
```

It gives, `Maximum call stack size exceeded`, Why? I called my version like this:

```
lengthy(1)
```

Comment: What is the size of the list with which you are calling?

Comment: Do you mean to pass in an array or a list of values?

Comment: The recursive call passes an Array even though the initial call does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the spread syntax in the recursive call, otherwise you will pass an array as first argument, and the *rest* argument will then be an empty array. This will go on endlessly.

So do:

```js
var lengthy = (first, ...rest) => 
    first === undefined ? 0 : 1 + lengthy(...rest);    
    
console.log(lengthy(1,2,3,8,11));
```

Note that on the initial call *rest* is an array, which has all the remaining arguments in it. In the example above, *rest* will be `[2,3,8,11]`. This is what the rest syntax does for you.

Now you can see how your recursive call would look of you would not spread that array again:

```
 lengthy(rest)
```

...becomes

```
 lengthy([2,3,8,11])
```

So now the arguments in the recursive call are:

```
 first = [2,3,8,11]
 rest = []
```

If you continue this analysis, you'll see the next call is with:

```
 first = []
 rest = []
```

And this will go on for ever.

Now with the correction `lengthy(...rest)`, the actual call will be in the example:

```
 lengthy(2,3,8,11)
```

... which is what you want. Now the next value of `first` and `rest` will be:

```
 first = 2
 rest = [3,8,11]
```

...etc.

Comment: Your solution worked. Can you tell me the ideology behind passing `...rest` again? I've not yet encountered such behavior in the book.

Comment: This is the way to go. Nitpick, at the call site, it's called "spread" instead of "rest" since you're "spreading" the collection out as individual arguments.

Comment: @RajatSaxena, I added some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The answer has to do with [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

In the original, you have:

```
([first, ...rest])
```

In the second answer, you have:

```
(first, ...rest)
```

The original takes a single array as an argument, and destructures the array so that the first element is in `first` and the remaining are in `rest`.

The second does not destructure the array and plops the array that you pass in into first, leaving `rest` to be an empty array.  This is called recursively. And on all recursive calls to `lengthy`, `rest` is never empty.

Comment: I'm calling my version as `lengthy(1, 2, 3)`. Now?

Comment: This won't work either since `rest` is never undefined. It will be the empty list

Comment: This works: `var lengthy = (first, ...rest) =>    first === undefined || first.length === 0 ? 0 : 1 + lengthy(rest)`

Answer (score 1):

```
var lengthy = ([first, ...rest]) => first === undefined ? 0 : 1 + lengthy(rest)
// lengthy gets passed ONE argument, an array
```

This most likely because first is never evaluating to 0 which causes an infinite loop.

`length` accepts ONE argument which is an array.

`lengthy` accepts an arbitrary number of arguments, and counts them, but when you are calling it recursively you are only passing it ONE.

So when `lengthy` is called for the second time, `...rest` is `undefined` and is passed in the recursive call to lengthy which means `first` will from then on only be `undefined` and cause your error.

Comment: `lengthy` accepts an arbitrary number of arguments, and counts them.

Comment: @Oriol: Ah, yes thanks.  I've amended my answer accrodingly